# Printing two strings into register

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I keep getting an error if I try to do the following:

```
TITLE            (Filename.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
    name BYTE "Jdoe", 0
    menu BYTE "Hello user of this computer!", 0dh, 0ah,
        "I am a robot AI designed to help you with you programs", 0dh, 0ah,
        "Please allow me to assist you as you work on your program", 0dh, 0ah,
        "Name Please> ", 0

.code
main PROC
    ; instructions are added here, in the main procedure
    ; which is in the code segment

    mov EDX, OFFSET menu
    call WriteString

    mov EDX, OFFSET name
    call WriteString

    call Crlf

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

At line 26, I basically get an error that says `initializer magnitude too large for specified size`. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.   Line 26 is `mov edx, OFFSET name`

Comment: Are you sure that's line 26? What are you not showing? Anyway, verify your assembler allows for multi-line constants as you have used for `menu`.

Comment: @Jester It works if I omit the second part of the program, which is to print out `name`.  Printing out `menu` works fine.

Comment: Maybe `name` is a reserved word? Try changing that. Also please add tag for assembler used ... I am guessing it is `masm`? According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esw1f486.aspx) `name` is an ignored reserved word.

Comment: @Jester Looks like that was the issue. Could you post this as an answer so I can credit you? Thanks!

Comment: add comment to show which line you're indicating. People won't count lines for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esw1f486.aspx) `name` is a reserved word which has no function (it is ignored) but you are still not allowed to use it. Pick a different identifier.